# Knockout Foreach binding to html table not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, knockout.js

I have been working on this issue for a while. I am new to Knockout.

I have an html page with a table that I want displayed using Knockout. If I hardcode the JSON array, it works! When I use the $.getJSON function, it does not work.

A little background: I cannot use any server-side languages for this project- a CMS is being used that will not allow server-side stuff.

I get the JSON from a table of data I download, then pass it to this to make displaying, styling, etc. automated so that all the user has to do is upload the file with the html table and the rest is taken care of.

If there is an easier way, I am definitely open to suggestions. My question is: how do I make the foreach data display?

Here is my fiddle with some test data:
https://jsfiddle.net/xtw3nf8q/

**HTML**

```
<table>     
<tbody data-bind="foreach: teststuff">    
<tr>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.testone"></td>            
        <td data-bind="text: $data.testtwo"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.testthree"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.testfour"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.testfive"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.testsix"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: $data.testseven"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**jQuery/Knockout**

```
$.getJSON( "/echo/json/jsonfile.txt", function( data ) {
ko.applyBindings({
teststuff: data
});
});
```

Here is the jsonfile.txt contents:

```
[{"testone":"Number","testtwo":"49","testthree":"49","testfour":"49","testfive":"49","testsix":"49","testseven":""},{"testone":"Reporting","testtwo":"0","testthree":"0","testfour":"0","testfive":"0","testsix":"0","testseven":"0.0 %"},{"testone":"Area","testtwo":"0","testthree":"0","testfour":"0","testfive":"0","testsix":"0","testseven":""},{"testone":"K. BACA","testtwo":"0","testthree":"0","testfour":"0","testfive":"0","testsix":"0","testseven":"N/A"},{"testone":"D. GRAY","testtwo":"0","testthree":"0","testfour":"0","testfive":"0","testsix":"0","testseven":"N/A"},{"testone":"J. ISA","testtwo":"0","testthree":"0","testfour":"0","testfive":"0","testsix":"0","testseven":"N/A"},{"testone":"Number","testtwo":"49","testthree":"49","testfour":"49","testfive":"49","testsix":"49","testseven":""},{"testone":"Reporting","testtwo":"0","testthree":"0","testfour":"0","testfive":"0","testsix":"0","testseven":"0.0 %"},{"testone":"Area","testtwo":"0","testthree":"0","testfour":"0","testfive":"0","testsix":"0","testseven":""},{"testone":"T. BARK","testtwo":"0","testthree":"0","testfour":"0","testfive":"0","testsix":"0","testseven":"N/A"},{"testone":"H. LAND","testtwo":"0","testthree":"0","testfour":"0","testfive":"0","testsix":"0","testseven":"N/A"},{"testone":"F. JONES","testtwo":"0","testthree":"0","testfour":"0","testfive":"0","testsix":"0","testseven":"N/A"},{"testone":"D. KNOWLES","testtwo":"0","testthree":"0","testfour":"0","testfive":"0","testsix":"0","testseven":"N/A"}]
```

I downloaded the KnockoutJS plugin/extension for Chrome to help debug and that got me to this point. There are now no errors in the developer console; when I console.log "data", it shows my data. I am at a loss!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable (they support Knockout). More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The full content of my question is here- do I need to include all of my code as well?

Comment: Yes -- that's probably the most important part of the content. See the links above.

Comment: Actually your code should work. Is there any error in browser's console?

Comment: There are no errors shown in console in Chrome, Firefox, or IE.

Comment: The problem is demonstrably not to do with your knockout, but instead to do with your getJSON call (or the result returned). As you're the only person who can debug that, Im not sure how you think we can answer this - except perhaps guesswork.

Comment: Guesswork commenced, interested if I'm right :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You've asked the server for text! It's given you a string

```
$.getJSON( "/echo/json/jsonfile.txt", ....
```

You need to turn that string into a valid object (an array in this case):

```
$.getJSON( "/echo/json/jsonfile.txt", function( data ) {
    ko.applyBindings({
        teststuff: JSON.parse(data)
    });
});
```

Live example (using string data): https://jsfiddle.net/xtw3nf8q/4/

Comment: Now I'm getting somewhere- I have an error in the console now!

"SyntaxError: missing : after property id"

Looking into it now. I will let you know! Thank you for your response!!

Comment: @malmalz thats unrelated - there is no property `id` in any code you posted. I took your data, made it a string and proved this works - https://jsfiddle.net/xtw3nf8q/4/